# /usr/local/bin/kubectl: line 1: syntax error: unexpected redirection

Tags: github-actions, kubectl

Today when I run the kubectl step in github actions, shows error:

```
Run steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
/usr/bin/docker run --name c84860f61e3163354304ab2d0b753ecef9fd_7e2fa2 --label 55c848 --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "INPUT_CONFIG" -e "INPUT_COMMAND" -e "INPUT_VERSION" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/texhub-web/texhub-web":"/github/workspace" 55c848:60f61e3163354304ab2d0b753ecef9fd  "latest" "***" "set image --record deployment/texhub-web texhub-web=***/reddwarf-pro/texhub-web:81ac2189d08024b5d9ab6be6dd69c8117d765e33 -n reddwarf-pro"
using kubectl@v1.28.3
/usr/local/bin/kubectl: line 1: syntax error: unexpected redirection
```

why did this happen? I can use the kubectl get the namespace like this:

```
> kubectl get ns
NAME               STATUS   AGE
ambassador         Active   655d
calico-apiserver   Active   16d
calico-system      Active   16d
default            Active   2y77d
kube-node-lease    Active   2y77d
kube-public        Active   2y77d
kube-system        Active   2y77d
lens-metrics       Active   153d
reddwarf-cache     Active   2y76d
reddwarf-monitor   Active   430d
reddwarf-pro       Active   2y76d
reddwarf-storage   Active   2y76d
reddwarf-toolbox   Active   671d
sre                Active   2y75d
tigera-operator    Active   16d
```

I did not change the configuration of the github actions recently. what should I do to fix it? BTW, this is the github action steps define:

```
  - name: deploy to cluster
    uses: steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0
    with: # defaults to latest kubectl binary version
      config: ${{ secrets.KUBE_CONFIG_DATA }}
      command: set image --record deployment/texhub-web texhub-web=registry.cn-hongkong.aliyuncs.com/reddwarf-pro/texhub-web:${{ github.sha }} -n reddwarf-pro
```

Comment: How did you install `kubectl`? The error looks like what you’d get if you tried to download the binary but got an error page instead.

Comment: I did not install the kubectl, it is handled by `steebchen/kubectl@v2.0.0` step I think.

Comment: Does any other command work configured with `command` input parameter e.g. `get pods`, `get ns`?

Comment: BTW, `kucectl` is  [preinstalled on Ubuntu runners](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners/about-github-hosted-runners#preinstalled-software) that you can directly use instead.